# leer archivos .xml en orden inverso

Tags: php, xml

Estoy generando la lectura y escritura de archivos `.xml` mediante php, el problema es que aparecen del primero al ultimo y yo quiero que los ultimos en añadirse sean los primeros en aparecer.

Aquí esta el código:

```
<?php
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $conta; $i++) {
            $usuario = simplexml_load_file('xml/' . $i . '.xml');
            echo '<div style="background-color:#F6A6A6;width:800px;height:200px;border-radius:50px;margin-top:10px;">';
            echo '<div style="color:white;"><br>';
            echo '<label style="float:bottom;float:left;padding-left:40px;font-family: Dancing Script, cursive;font-size:20px;color:black">Nombre: &nbsp</label>';
            echo '<label style="font-family: Courgette, cursive;font-size:16px;">';
            echo $usuario->Tiempo[0]->nombre;
            echo '</label>';
            echo '</div>';


            echo '<div style="color:white;"><br>';
            echo '<label style="float:bottom;float:left;padding-left:40px;font-family: Dancing Script, cursive;font-size:20px;color:black">E-mail: &nbsp</label>';
            echo '<label style="font-family: Courgette, cursive;font-size:16px;">';
            echo $usuario->Tiempo[0]->correo;
            echo '</label>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div style="color:white;"><br>';
            echo '<label style="float:bottom;float:left;padding-left:40px;font-family: Dancing Script, cursive;font-size:20px;color:black">Mensaje: &nbsp</label>';
            echo '<label style="font-family: Courgette, cursive;font-size:16px;">';
            echo $usuario->Tiempo[0]->mensaje;
            echo '</label>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div><br><br>';
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Imagino que todo lo generas también desde una base de datos. Tal vez la solución proviene desde la Base de Datos. Porque no colocas también lo que generas de la base de datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahora mismo el bucle `for` que muestra los comentarios/mensajes va desde 1 hasta `$conta`, una posible solución para mostrarlos en orden inverso sería hacer que el bucle `for` vaya desde `$conta` hasta 1:

```
for ($i = $conta; $i >= 1; $i--) {
    // el resto de tu código se mantiene igual
```

Comment: muchas gracias, alvaro, ya lo eh resuelto, de hecho no tarde en darme cuenta de ese detalle y si fue así como lo solucione, hasta pronto